# jQuery Audio Player - Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found

Tags: jquery, audio-player

For a language learning site, I created my own audio player.

On a page, there are  always a few player buttons, each one is meant to play the sound corresponding to a specific example.

The problem is that from time to time, some of the audios fail to play and I get "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found." in console. This error is always random, it affects different audios at different times. If I refresh the page, especially with clearing cache, I can play the audio that did not play before.

I've tried to solve it by catching the error and trying to fetch the audio again but it seems I'm doing something wrong.

I'd be very grateful for any help.

Here is the code of the player:

HTML/PHP:

```
<div class="player_cont">
    <!-- NORMAL PLAYBACK SPEED -->
    <a id="player_<?php echo $id; ?>_n" class="player play" data-id="<?php echo $id; ?>_n" data-audio="<?php echo $audio; ?>" data-speed="1" data-playing="0"></a>
    <!-- SLOWED DOWN PLAYBACK SPEED -->
    <a id="player_<?php echo $id; ?>_s" class="player play slow" data-id="<?php echo $id; ?>_s" data-audio="<?php echo $audio; ?>" data-speed="0.7" data-playing="0"></a>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var $ = jQuery;

    var playerBtns = $('.player'); // get all the player buttons on the page
    var audios = new Array(); // array for collecting audio files for each player ID
    
    // populate the audios array with audio files
    playerBtns.each(function(index, player) {
        var audio = new Audio($(player).data('audio'));
        var id = $(player).data('id');
        audios[id] = audio;
    }); 

    // when player button is clicked
    playerBtns.on("click",function() {

        var id = $(this).data('id');
        var player = $('#player_' + id);
        var speed = player.data('speed');
        var isPlaying = player.attr('data-playing');

        // if audio was not playing, play it
        if (isPlaying == 0) {
            player.removeClass('play').addClass('pause').attr('data-playing', 1);
            
            var playPromise = audios[id].play();
            if (playPromise !== undefined) {
                playPromise.then(function() {
                    audios[id].playbackRate = speed;
                    audios[id].play();
                    isPlaying = 1;
                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                    // try to fetch the audio file again
                    var playerRetry = $('#player_' + id);
                    var audioRetry = new Audio($(playerRetry).data('audio'));
                    audioRetry.play(); // <-- it never works out
                });
            }

        } 
        // if audio was playing, pause it
        else {
            player.removeClass('pause').addClass('play').attr('data-playing', 0);
            audios[id].pause();
            isPlaying = 0;
        }
        
        // when audio finished playing
        audios[id].onended = function() {
            player.removeClass('pause').addClass('play').attr('data-playing', 0);
            isPlaying = 0;
        };
    });

});
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After a few long months of struggling I fugured out that the issue was not in my code but was caused by a PWA WordPress plugin.

Disabling the plugin and fully clearing the browser cache and cookies removed the issue all together.